# Expectation with a "regular" function

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I hope this is not a silly question. I know that the expectation of a constant is just a constant (i.e. $E[c]=c$ for $c\in \mathbb{R}$), and that for a function $g$ of a random variable X,  $E[g(X)]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x)~f(x)~dx$ (in the continuous case).

But, what if you have something like $E[cx^2 X^3]$? I know you can take the $c$ out: $cE[x^2 X^3]$ but can you do the same with the $x^2$? Is it still considered like a "constant" even though it's a function of $x$ (but still not a random variable)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, a random variable is a function $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, where $\Omega$ is your underlying probability space.  Then a "constant" is just a function $x:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ which is constant - that is, no matter what the result of your underlying experiment happens to be, $x$ always has the same value.

So, for instance, $\DeclareMathOperator*{\E}{\mathbb{E}}\E[cx^2X^3]=cx^2\E[X^3]$, assuming $x$ is constant in this sense - even though $x$ doesn't strictly have a numerical value.

This is useful for things like the moment generating function and the characteristic function of a random variable: they can be defined as
$$
t\mapsto\E[e^{tX}]\qquad\text{and}\qquad t\mapsto\E[e^{itX}],
$$
respectively. Clearly, $t$ is an unknown quantity; but it is not considered random, as it doesn't depend on the random choice of $X$.

Comment: Oh ok that really makes sense. I was thinking along those lines but I wasn't too sure. Thank you so much to you both for your answer, @MLT, nrpeterson

Answer (score 0):

The $x$ you have in the integral $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x)~f(x)~dx$$ is a dummy variable. Its the variable of integration. You can just as well replace it with, say $y$

Then you will realize that you can take out $x^2$ from $E[cx^2 X^3]$ and get $cx^2 E[X^3]$.